# Rounded Corners in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-9, rounded-corners

I am trying to place a `seperate CSS` for all the versions of `IE` and trying to work with the below CSS but it's not giving me any `rounded` `corners`.

Can anyone point me out the right path

Here is my CSS:

```
   -moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    display:none;
    background-color:#ddeef6;
    position:absolute;
    width:230px;
    z-index:150;
    border:1px transparent;
    text-align:left;
    top: 24.5px; 
    right:84px; 
    margin-top:-53px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    *margin-right: -1px;
    color:#789;
    font-size:11px;
    padding: 5px;
```

And I tried by adding below url's none worked out for me and I think they work absolutely perfect as beore I have used them and then it worked well but in this case something went wrong with my css part.

```
behavior url('css/PIE.htc')
behavior url('css/ie-css.htc')
behavior url('css/border-radius.htc')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using vendor-specific rules in your CSS. Use the "standardized" version for IE9:

```
border-radius: 5px 0 5px 5px;
```

The `-moz-` specific rules can be shortened in a similar manner. Webkit (to my knowledge) doesn't allow the short form.

Here's some additional information: [border-radius](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/).

Comment: @Jonah-Thank you much it worked perfectly and I need only top left,bottom right and bottom left so how do I change that?

Comment: The rule I've provided should do all 4 corners. I believe the order is top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left. If you want to specify them individually, just use: `border-bottom-left-radius` etc.

Comment: That did the magic-And thanks once again for pointing me out the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Add border-radius-topleft:5px; 
    border-radius-bottomleft:5px; 
    border-radius-bottomright:5px;